# Newsletter digest based on user selection of taxonomies terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, emails

I've looked through forums and modules for a few days trying to find this and nothing seemed to quite fit what I'm looking for.  I want to see if this can be done with existing modules before I venture to create my own or hire it out.

A specific content type has a few fields, one of those fields being a taxonomy vocabulary where an author can tag the content with a few terms.

A user can 'subscribe' to those terms on their user profile.

Once a week (or a designated time period), a digest of new content with the terms that a user has subscribed to is sent out via e-mail to the user.  If there is no new content, nothing is sent out for the specific user.

---

One way I thought of doing it is generate a view based on a users taxonomy subscriptions.  Some how run through each user and e-mail that view.  But, not sure how to even go about starting that.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?